# Rails tagging solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tagging

I'm looking to add tagging to an application which I'm currently building.

Basically it's a simple quiz system and I want admins who enter the quiz questions to be able to tag them appropriately. These tags will then be used to make sure the correct quiz is generated for the correct user type and also for reporting purposes.

I looked around for a bit and found a quite a few tagging plugins out there. Can anyone recommend a tagging solution that will suit my requirements?